# New thread life-cycle within Tkinter object

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

I've got an issue with working with the threading class within a Tkinter GUI. On initiating the Tkinter GUI, I create new Threading & Queue objects with a daemon and start it. In the Tkinter GUI, I have a button that calls an internal method. This method then calls put on the Queue object and is posted below. The Threading object performs all the necessary actions that I expect.

```
def my_method_threaded(self, my_name):
    try:
        self.queue.put(("test", dict(name=my_name)))
        self.label_str_var.set('')
        self.queue.join()
    except:
        self.error_out(msg=traceback.format_exc())
```

However, I am encountering an issue AFTER it has finished. If I call `self.queue.join()`, then the `set` call is never executed and the app freezes after the thread has completed its task. If I comment out the `join()` command, the `set` call IS executed, but the button will only work the first time, after it does nothing (I am tracking what the `run()` method is doing using a logger. It is only ever called the first time).

I am assuming there is an issue with calling join() and the Tkinter loop, which is why the first issue occurs. Can anyone shed any light on the second issue? If you need more code, then let me know.

Edit: A second issue I've just noticed is that the `while True` loop executes my action twice even though I have called `self.queue.task_done()`. Code for the run method is below:

```
  def run(self):
    args     = self._queue.get()
    my_name  = args[1]["name"]
    while True:
      if my_name == "Barry":
          #calls a static method elsewhere

      self.queue.task_done()
```

Comment: Is it possible that .join() is killing or blocking the Tk main loop?

Comment: Can you post some more code? Maybe the code where you create the button and the code where `run` and `my_method` each get called? It's hard to figure out what's going on, how you expect the code to work, and which thread each of these methods is running in.

Comment: I can post more code later. However, the button's command parameter is a lambda function calling my_method_threaded. I have the code working as I want without using threads. In that instance, I have a method called my_method that, rather than creating a thread to execute the static method, executes it directly.

Comment: If you are running Python 3.x, I know of a library you could use that allows `tkinter` to work fine within a threaded environment.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not. Python 2.6 on Win7 x64, and I'm restricted to using a pre-defined set of libraries for app portability. The only reason I'm attempting to thread the calls is because they can be lengthy, and are blocking the tk thread. If this is just a known issue, I'll just have to tackle the issue from a different angle.